# Can't seem to use PIP to install my own module

Tags: python, pip

I am following the 2nd edition of *Head First Python* by Paul Barry to try and learn to use python. I've made it to a point where I have created a function, put it in a module, then created a distribution file for that modules. Now I want to install it on my computer, but I can't seem to get the distribution file to run on my computer.

My code inserted into Windows 10 command prompt and the resulting errors:

```html
C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\mymodules\dist> py -3 -m pip install vlsearch-1.0.tar
Requirement 'vlsearch-1.0.tar' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing c:\users\coolt\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\mymodules\dist\vlsearch-1.0.tar
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 809, in unpack_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 715, in unpack_file_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 602, in unpack_file
    tarfile.is_tarfile(filename) or
  File "C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tarfile.py", line 2448, in is_tarfile
    t = open(name)
  File "C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tarfile.py", line 1569, in open
    return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tarfile.py", line 1634, in gzopen
    fileobj = gzip.GzipFile(name, mode + "b", compresslevel, fileobj)
  File "C:\Users\coolt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\gzip.py", line 163, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\coolt\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\mymodules\\dist\\vlsearch-1.0.tar'
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I'm very confused because the file definitely exists in the spot that I am specifying. How do I get it installed?

[the file exists in the folder that I expect it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdbM3.png)

Comment: Well, the file you have given does not exist.

Comment: Have you navigated to the directory where you expect `vlsearch-1.0.tar` To be and confirm it exists and file name is correct etc?

Comment: i added a pic showing the file in the specified destination

Comment: Sure that user for Thomas Gauldin is coolt?

Comment: coolt is the same thing as Thomas Gaudin. It's the only user account on the computer